# Radio button selection is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am facing an issue with the existing code which is using html and JS. The page has a html table which has a radio button and 4 other fields. The table is created dynamically when we set values through controller. Also I can add new rows in the table which is done completly through JS. Now the problem is I inserted 2 rows from controller and added a new row through a button click. So I have 3 radio button now. If I select one radio button among the controller inserted row it selects only one, which is fine, If I select the 3rd one I can see two selected radio button, which is not correct. In any case it should select only one. when I take view source I am not seeing the entry for the javascript added new row, so I hope the problem is because of the Id generated ? please let me know how can I solve this issue?

Java controller

```
List <MyQuestion> fetchedQuestions =  AppImpl.getMyQuestions(id);

            for (int index=0; index< fetchedQuestions.size() ; index++){
                MyQuestion questionsToAdd= fetchedQuestions.get(index);
                questionList.add(questionsToAdd);

            }

            myqstntemplate.setMyQuestions(questionList);
            templatebean.setQuestionTemplate(myqstntemplate);

        }
```

JScode

```
function addRow(){
    isDirty=true;
     if(document.getElementById('value').value != 'value'){
        rowNumber = document.getElementById('questionsSize').value;
        document.getElementById('value').value='value';//other option is novalue
    } 

    var questionId=document.getElementById('questionsSize').value;
    questionId=parseInt(questionId)+1;
    document.getElementById('questionsSize').value = questionId;
    var newRow = $('<tr/>').attr('id', 'row' + rowNumber);
    //Add some HTML to the row
    newRow.html('<td><input type="hidden" id="newQuestion'+rowNumber+'" value="'+questionId+'"/><input id="question" name="question" type="radio" style="width:20px;" value=""  onclick="setSelectedQuestion(\''+rowNumber+'\',\'new\')"/></td><td class="newRow" align="center" style="vertical-align: middle;">'+questionId+'<input type="hidden" value="newQuestion"/></td> <td colspan="2"><input style="width: 397px;" id="myQstnTemplate.questions['+rowNumber+'].question" name="myQstnTemplate.questions['+rowNumber+'].question" type="text" value=""  maxlength="256" onclick="enableDirty()" style="text-align:left;"/><div id="pencil" title="Edit helptext" class="pencil-img fltRight" style="border: 0pt;padding-right: 15px; " onclick="displayHelpText('+rowNumber+',\'new\');return false;"></div><input id="myQstnTemplate.questions['+rowNumber+'].questionId" name="myQstnTemplate.questions['+rowNumber+'].questionId" type="hidden" value="-1" /><input style="width: 350px;" id="myQstnTemplate.questions['+rowNumber+'].helptext" name="myQstnTemplate.questions['+rowNumber+'].helptext" type="hidden" value="" onclick="enableDirty()" style="text-align:left;"/></td><td><select style="width:100px;" id="myQstnTemplate.questions['+rowNumber+'].schemeId" name="myQstnTemplate.questions['+rowNumber+'].schemeId"><option value="-1">Select</option><c:forEach var="answer" items="${myqstionTemplateBean.answerTypes}"><option title="${answer.questions}" value="${answer.displaySchemeId}">${answer.answerTypeName}</option></c:forEach></select></td> <td><div><input type="hidden" id="question'+rowNumber+'" name="question'+rowNumber+'" value="'+rowNumber+'"/><select id="myQstnTemplate.questions['+rowNumber+'].ansId" name="myQstnTemplate.questions['+rowNumber+'].ansId" style="width:100%"><option value="-1">Select</option><c:forEach var="ansId" items="${myqstionTemplateBean.ansIds}"><option value="${ansId}" <c:if test="${ansId eq question.ansId}">selected</c:if>>${ansId}</option></c:forEach></select></div></td>');
    //Append the new row to the body of the #myTable table
        $('#qstionTable tbody').append(newRow);
                        //Iterate row number
    rowNumber++;

}
```

Comment: Quote: "Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: You should include your code, but my guess is that you haven't set the name of the added radiobutton correctly. Radio buttons are grouped by their names, so the third RB need to have the same name as the first two. The reason you cannot see the RB in the source code is that the source code don't include dynamically created elements; if you right-click the RB and click "Inspect element" you will see it in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all the radio button working together you should have **the same name** for each in your template.
Check that.
Edit:
If several radio button can be selected it is because their name are differents. Your radio' name must not depend of the rowNumber. Set a hard name, not a variable name.
Check that.

Comment: it worked  , problem was with the name when it created dynamically. Thanks Stages for your help.